# Problem when getting 'Authorization' header on test Flask application with FlaskClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-testing

I'm testing my Flask application using FlaskClient, in order to avoid to run a Flask server always when I'm testing my application.

I've created a 'sign_in' view that returns an 'Authorization' header with a encrypted token when the user logs successfully in my front-end.

This view works normally in a normal environment, it returns the 'Authorization' header correctly, however when I'm testing this view, inside the test environment, it does not return the 'Authorization' header. The view returns `None` in 'Authorization' header.

I've already tried some solutions on the internet, such as to add `self.app.config['TESTING'] = True` in my test case, but the terminal raises an error `'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'config'` that I've already tried to look for a solution, but without success.

I would like to know what may be happening.

Does anyone know any solution for this question?

I send my code below for analysis.

Thank you in advance.

**view.py**

```
@app.route("/sign_in", methods = ["POST"])
def sign_in():
    ...

    username, password = ...

    try:
        encoded_jwt_token = auth_login(username, password)
    except UserDoesNotExistException as error:
        return str(error), error.status_code

    resp = Response("Returned Token")
    resp.headers['Authorization'] = encoded_jwt_token

    return resp
```

**test.py**

```
class TestAPIAuthLogin(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = catalog_app.test_client()
        # self.app.config['TESTING'] = True  # config does not exist

    def test_get_api_auth_login_user_test(self):
        username = "test"
        password = get_string_in_hash_sha512("test")
        authorization = 'Basic ' + get_string_in_base64(username + ":" + password)

        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': authorization
        }

        response = self.app.get('/sign_in', headers=headers)
        # it returns None 
        authorization = response.headers.get("Authorization")

        self.assertIsNotNone(authorization)
        self.assertNotEqual(authorization, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be to do with the way HTTP requests process headers, where they capitalise them and add `HTTP_` as a prefix. Try changing your header to `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` instead of just `Authorization`, since the test client will not be setting this properly.

Comment: I tried to get this header instead of `Authorization`, however this tip did not work, unfortunately. I printed the list of headers that are returned and there is not an `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header, but there is an `Authorization` header that returns `None`. Thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry for being unclear, I meant you should add `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` in the request header, so your request would be:

`headers = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json','HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': authorization}`

Comment: I tried to follow your tip, but it did not work yet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Now I've figure out what was happening. I tried to describe in an answer. Thank you for your help Kathy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys for this silly question.
Now I've figure the answer out.
The problem was that I was trying to do a `GET` request in a view that is using a `POST` method.

I've just replaced the request from

`response = self.app.get('/sign_in', headers=headers)`

to

`response = self.app.post('/sign_in', headers=headers)`

and now it started to work.

I will let this question here in case of someone gets the same silly error.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If similar issue for DRF clients, You can use,

```
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {token}'.format(token=token))
```

Ref: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs